# Node js convert ascii to decimall

Tags: arrays, node.js, decimal, ascii

I have an array that looks contains say [6 5 7 7], however it is stored in ascii so it is [54 53 55 55]. I want to have it as the actual decimal values not ascii. I feel like the conversion back to decimal is simple, but I am unsure what the comman would be. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the ASCII values in an array called `asciiValues` you can do something like this:

```
var asciiValues = [54, 53, 55, 55];

var decimalValues = asciiValues.map(function(val) {
    return Number(String.fromCharCode(val));
});

console.log(decimalValues); // [6, 5, 7, 7]
```

`String.fromCharCode` will take the ASCII code and return the string representation. You can then use the `Number` constructor to turn it into an actual number.

Comment: Thanks for quick simple response! exaclty what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array variable is named `arr`, the following statement will convert every element to a Number:

```
arr.map(Number);
```